# Can the watch command be used as a hook?

Tags: files, watch

Is it possible to use the watch command (in a pinch...ie without installing other software on Redhat) with `ls` to monitor a directory for files created so that when they are created a command can be run, and then the watch command exited, was would be a "file creation hook?

Comment: You want to `watch ls` and when ever a new file/folder created , you want watch command to exit ?

Comment: You *could* use a hydraulic jack to open a garage door, but you're really better off figuring out what's wrong with the torsion spring instead... (get `incron`)

Comment: @Ten-Coin Correct...but I'd also like a command to run there after

Comment: @IgancioVazquez-Abrams Not every has root...I'm aware there are better options, but they aren't always options.

Comment: Any reason you want to use watch for this? There is no obvious way for watch to do it, but I'm sure you could hack something together. Did you consider a normal loop?

Comment: @MikaelKjaer Doing isn't that wasteful?  I always thought that you should somehow subscribe to updates from the directory, and the directory will let you know if it changes rather than your program wasting CPU cycles and continually looking to see if the directory has been updated.  (Of course I'm not really sure what that entails for the CPU when I subscribe to it either)  I suppose you could slow it down with a sleep(ms) call but what I'm looking for shouldn't take that long to show up in the directory anyway; but if it doesn't at all..then what?  I'm using watch because it is available.

Comment: How many files and how often should this happen since you think CPU is going to be an issue? I would assume a sleep would be enough. On top of my mind something like this: `while [ ! -f test1.txt ]; do sleep 1; done && echo exists`

Comment: @MikaelKjaer Actually what's happening is I'm running a command the process displays a UI, it then opens another process/UI which I want to go away..and that 2nd UI being opened creates a file the 2nd UI disappears when I remove that file.  Presently I have to wait for visual confirmation that the UI is displayed before removing the file, but if I could as you say, code a while loop to look for the file then I wouldn't need to bother with the visual confirmation I'd just know that the file for the 2nd process/ui had been deleted and that the 2nd UI / Process would go away on its own...

Comment: check `inotifywait` too. In this case, it should perhaps be used without -m

Comment: @a.B. That's too new and it needs installed, I don't have that luxury.